# SQL 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups Failover Successfully But Application Complains About Login Failed for User

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, sql-server-2012, alwayson

I am trying to get SQL 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups working for an application. The cluster has 2 SQL nodes and 1 witness server.

Everything appears to be failing over successfully when I do simple tests. 
Ex.

- Manual failover using SQL Management Studio then execute a SELECT statement successfully.
- Stop SQL service on primary server then execute a SELECT statement successfully.

That seems to prove that failover is working correctly. When I try to stop the SQL service while an application is running, I get failed login attempts for the SQL user.

SQL logs say:

Edit: Now I am getting the following:

Login failed for user 'sql_user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'database_name'. [CLIENT: xx.xx.xx.xx]

Application logs pretty much say the same thing that the SQL user cannot login.

What would be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Does the login exist on the second node? That is, if you run `select * from sys.server_principals where name = 'sql_user'`, do you get anything back?

Comment: Did you use the listener connection string?

Comment: @BenThul I ran the command on both nodes and it exists on both. The behaviour is odd because if I start up the application on either node it will startup with no issues. When I failover, it gives me the above error. When I fail back over, it recovers successfully.

Comment: @JimB Yes the application uses the listeners's connection string. The tests in SQL Management Studio also use the listener's connection string as well.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that the logins SID on the database are different from the server logins. I thought I resolved this issue by deleting the database logins and then changing the user mapping for the server login after. I thought it was working but when I added a 3rd node to the cluster, the user login issue still persisted.